# Is the Runway Visual Range (RVR) communicated to the pilots?

Tags: runways, approach, go-around

During CAT IIIA/IIIB approach where the decision height is 50 ft/0 ft, if the Runway Visual Range requirement for the approach is not met, what is a pilot to do?

I mean, 50 ft (or even 100 ft?) seem so low enough  that a go around can not be initiated. Unless the pilot knows the RVR beforehand how can he be sure to perform CAT III approach?

Comment: They get the RVR via radio, they can get up to three different RVRs too, touchdown, mid-point and rollout.

Answer (score 4):

Pilots get the RVR values either from weather reports or directly from ATC. RVR also shows up on ATIS reports when visibility drops to less than 1 mile. ATC will have a realtime readout of RVR and can communicate these values to pilots at any time by radio.

ATC RVR display

[image]

Source: [http://mtechsystems.com](http://mtechsystems.com/corporation/company-news-2012.html)

The CAT III approach should only be commenced if the ceiling and RVR values meet the minimum for the approach in use and for the current aircraft equipment status. Some airlines will have their own minimums which can differ from the published CAT III minimums.

Pilots will often ask for the latest ceiling and RVR values while doing the approach. ATC will also announce any changes or reduction in ceiling or RVR values while aircraft are on approach. If the new values are below limits, the crew should commence a go-around.

A go-around can be done from any altitude and the wheels can touch the runway during the go-around. Low atlitude, "Low Energy" go-arounds are practiced during re-current Simulator training.

Comment: So if I understand it correct a go around can be initiated even when the main landing gear touches ground?

Comment: Yes, most aircraft/airline procedures will say as long as reverse has not been selected, you may initiate a go-around.

Comment: Is RVR usually on the ATIS?

Comment: When would ceiling be controlling for a Cat III approach? Vis, yes, but ceiling???

Comment: Certain CAT III approaches require a decision height.  It can vary according to aircraft type, equipment status, specific airline, or specific airport.

Comment: Under Part 91 approaches, the pilot can "take a peak" meaning that she can fly the approach even if the reported ceiling and viz  are below minima. Part 121 cannot begin the approach unless reported WX is above minima